# Is there an online malware scanner for browser? I recently had my firefox browser locked down by clicking on a picture in Facebook

Tags: malware

Is there an online malware scanner for browser? I recently had my firefox browser locked down by clicking on a picture in Facebook.Firefox browser, locked untill hard shutdown, after reboot the browser asked if i wanted to restore settings. I did not

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? If Facebook spreads malware you can't do much about it other than blocking Facebook. There are online filtering tools that claim they filter malicious websites. Some of these options require setting up a specialized server in a different "gatekeeper" computer.

Comment: "*Firefox browser, locked untill hard shutdown, after reboot the browser asked if i wanted to restore settings.*" seems to describe an ordinary crash. What leads you to believe that it was malware?